# How to redirect MongoDB logs in a Java application?

Tags: java, mongodb, logging

I am using a Mongo database in a Java application. 
The stdout is filled with logs of type:

```
dec. 09, 2017 9:45:21 AM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:225, serverValue:225}] to localhost:27017
dec. 09, 2017 9:45:21 AM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 4, 10]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=5, maxDocumentSize=16777216, roundTripTimeNanos=189205}
```

I would like these logs to be redirected to a text file. I tried several options mentioned in other SO answers without success, such as using `java.util.logging.Logger`, but I don't seem to get it to work. 
Help appreciated.

A sample of my code is the following:

```
MongoClient m = new MongoClient("localhost",27017);
// Do something with the DBs
m.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
// get mongo db logger
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("org.mongodb.driver");
// stop upstream log propagation
logger.setUseParentHandlers(false)
// set up handler for output to file
FileHandler fh = new FileHandler("S:/ome/path/to/your/file.log");
logger.addHandler(fh);
SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
fh.setFormatter(formatter);
```